# How to Adjust crossAxisCount(in gridview) based on gesturedetector

Tags: flutter, gridview

Like in the gallery app that it comes in our phones, when we zoom in we see less items, when we zoom out we see more items
Is there a way to achieve this in Flutter ?

Comment: Do you want something like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503316/11510697

Answer (score 0):

```
  double _scale=1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails scaleDetails) {
          setState(() {
            _scale = scaleDetails.horizontalScale;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap:true,
            gridDelegate:   SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: max(1, (16 / _scale).floor())),
            itemCount: 100 * 17,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GridTile(
                  child: Container(color:Colors.red,height:100,width:100 ,child: FlutterLogo(),));
            },

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**i have update some changes in exiting code of WarDoctor113 user according to you**

```
  double _scale = 1;
  int dynamicTotalCount =5;
  int maxCount =5;
  int minCount=2;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector(
      onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails scaleDetails) {
        setState(() {

          _scale = scaleDetails.horizontalScale;
          dynamicTotalCount=(16 / _scale).floor();

        });
      },
onScaleEnd:(ScaleEndDetails scaleDetails) {
  setState(() {

    _scale = scaleDetails.;
    dynamicTotalCount=(16 / _scale).floor();

  });
},
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: GridView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: max(minCount, dynamicTotalCount>=maxCount?maxCount:dynamicTotalCount)),
          itemCount: 100 * 17,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GridTile(
                child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: FlutterLogo(),
            ));
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: can i have your contact, i have an offer for you, to complete building a flutter app.

Comment: Here is my website https://codeashtraa.com/

Comment: How i can limit the crossAxisCount, like min crossAxisCount=2 and max of crossAxisCount will be like 5, so i have more control on it

Comment: Please look into the latest answer

Comment: it works good, but when i'm zooming if i took off my fingers it goes back to 5 So i can't see it only on 5, in the first code it works good, in the second it works the idea of having more control on it.
So what i mean is in the default i see 2 elements, when i zoom out it shows 3 if zoom out again it shows 4 and so on, and max is seeing 5 elements,  if i zoom in i see 3 elements and the min is 2, i hope i describe it well

Comment: here is my email id iwritecodeforyou@gmail.com